# Only discrete groups admit covering space actions?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, topological-groups

Somehow I seem to be missing something, since I expected to find an answer to this question somewhere but that is not so.

Suppose a topological group $G$ acts continuously on some $G$-space $X$. If the action is a covering space action (i.e. each $x\in X$ admits a neighborhood $U$, such that $gU\cap U=\emptyset$ for each $g\in G\setminus\lbrace e\rbrace$) is it necessarily true, that $G$ must be a discrete group?

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: There are so many posts on here, that just ask a simple question. If the moderators feel like they have to close or delete this question: well, that's out of my hands. Somebody competently answered my question and I am happy with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that for any $x \in X$, one may find a neighborhood $U_x$ containing $x$, which implies $gU_x \cap U_x = \varnothing$. Hence $gx \neq x$, so $G$ acts freely.

Since $\pi \colon X \to X / G$ is a covering map, each fiber $\pi^{-1}([x]) = Gx$ is a discrete subset of $X$. Let $\iota_x \colon G \to G \times X$ be the inclusion $g \mapsto (g,x)$. Since the action $\rho \colon G \times X \to X$ is continuous, the map $\rho_x = \rho \circ \iota_x \colon G \to Gx$, which is given by $\rho_x(g) = gx$, is also continuous.

Since $G$ acts freely, $\rho_x$ is injective, and thus a continuous bijection. The inverse is automatically continuous, as a map from a discrete space. Hence $G \cong Gx$, which implies $G$ is also discrete.

Comment: $Gx$ being discrete since $X\to X/G$ is a covering map was the missing link for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can also get this directly from the fact that $gU \cap U = \varnothing$. This means that open sets around points in the orbit are separated by $g$, and hence $Gx$ is discrete.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: @Shaun Why does my question not meet the standards of this site? I've looked at many apparently similar questions on here and could not find this specific question anywhere. Stack exchange sure is weird sometimes.

Comment: There's no context.

Comment: @Shaun The question is, if the group has to be discrete in order to admit a covering space action on some $G$-space $X$. What else do you want to know?

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/104041), @NicoZimmer.